# Is there a subtle difference between some_list[:] = another_list vs some_list = another_list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Like the title asks,
Is there a subtle difference between

```
some_list[:] = another_list
```

vs

```
some_list = another_list
```

I seen people do both and just ignored it, thinking of them as equivalents, but perhaps I'm missing a subtle difference?

Comment: The first is a slice assignment, it modifies `some_list` in place. The second makes the two variables refer to the same list.

Comment: There must be duplicates of this question, but I haven't been able to find them.

Comment: After reading the answer, I would have assumed so, but my minimum google search didn't find anything so I just asked anyways. didn't know it was that simple though

Comment: It's not so subtle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one will mutate the original list (`some_list`) while the second will simply create a new variable with a reference to `another_list`:

```
>>> some_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> another_list = [4, 5, 6]
>>> some_dict = {"foo": some_list}
>>> some_list[:] = another_list
>>> some_dict["foo"]
[4, 5, 6]
```

whereas

```
>>> some_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> another_list = [4, 5, 6]
>>> some_dict = {"foo": some_list}
>>> some_list = another_list
>>> some_dict["foo"]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Does the second example assign the memory address for `another_list` to `some_list` but the `some_list` stored as a value in the hash has the original address (and original list values)?

Comment: @ChrisCharley Yes. `some_list` is not pointing to the original list's (`[1, 2, 3]`) memory location anymore; but the dict value still does.